# sorting by.. title or link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort based on the title of a link to be formatted in an A-Z format.  I'm not able to change the html structure to be easily skinned, in a ul>li or div>div so I'm stuck with tr>tr>tr> and I can't figure out how to set the title to format property with a sort.

Here is my code. http://jsfiddle.net/34bMJ/

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
          if(typeof ul == "string")
            ul = $('tr tr tr');

          var lis = ul.find(".dl a");
          var vals = [];

          for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
            vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

          vals.sort();

          if(sortDescending)
            vals.reverse();

          for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
            lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
        }

        window.onload = function() {
          var desc = false;
          document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
            sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
            desc = !desc;
            return false;
          }
        }

<input type="button" id="test" value="Sort List (click again to reverse)"/>

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>

            <tr class="ccbnOutline"><td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3"><tbody>

                <tr class="ccbnBgTblTtl"><td><span class="ccbnTblTtl">Image</span></td><td><span class="ccbnTblTtl">Download</span></td></tr>

                <tr class="ccbnBgTblOdd"><td valign="top" width="10%"><span class="ccbnTblOdd"><img src="http://media.corporate-ir.net/media_files/IROL/25/253200/brand_jello.gif" border="0"></span></td><td valign="top" width="30%"><span class="dl"><a class="ccbnLnk" target="_blank" href="http://media.corporate-ir.net/media_files/IROL/25/253200/JELL-O.JPG">JELL-O.JPG</a><br></span></td></tr>

                    <tr class="ccbnBgTblEven"><td valign="top" width="10%"><span class="ccbnTblEven"><img src="http://media.corporate-ir.net/media_files/IROL/25/253200/brand_small_caprisun.gif" border="0"></span></td><td valign="top" width="30%"><span class="dl"><a class="ccbnLnk" target="_blank" href="http://library.corporate-ir.net/library/25/253/253200/mediaitems/32965/Capri Sun.jpg">Capri Sun.jpg</a><br></span></td>
                        </tr>
           </tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not correctly be able to understand the question. What I've understood is you want sorting on the basis of text written as Link.

This,

```
 ul = $('tr tr tr');
```

will not work

Write in this way:

```
 var lis = $('tr').find(".dl a");
```

Always do one thing when ever getting error in jsfiddle write word

```
debugger;
```

in the top of javascript block. Now press F12 and click run. Your debugging will start. Do add watch on the elements and you'll easily be able to find the solution.

Comment: I think you understand my question correctly.  I'll try to get it to sort using your method.